# Rancher 2 RKE cluster component kube-api-auth is throwing an error with v1Authenticate request

Tags: kubernetes, rancher-2

I’m facing a strange error in my RKE1 k8s cluster. Running 1.24.13 on vsphere. kube-api-auth is constantly throwing these errors in the logs:

```
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting Rancher Kube-API-Auth service on 127.0.0.1:6440"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Running in single server mode, will not peer connections"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting workload controllers"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting cluster.cattle.io/v3, Kind=ClusterUserAttribute controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting catalog.cattle.io/v1, Kind=ClusterRepo controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Role controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting /v1, Kind=Secret controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting /v1, Kind=ConfigMap controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Kind=ClusterRoleBinding controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Kind=RoleBinding controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1, Kind=ClusterRole controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:09Z" level=info msg="Starting cluster.cattle.io/v3, Kind=ClusterAuthToken controller"
time="2023-06-08T09:21:24Z" level=info msg="Processing v1Authenticate request..."
time="2023-06-08T09:21:24Z" level=error msg="found 1 parts of token"
time="2023-06-08T09:22:24Z" level=info msg="Processing v1Authenticate request..."
time="2023-06-08T09:22:24Z" level=error msg="found 1 parts of token"
time="2023-06-08T09:24:00Z" level=info msg="Processing v1Authenticate request..."
time="2023-06-08T09:24:00Z" level=error msg="found 1 parts of token"
```

I couldn't find anything in the Rancher support pages related to this or here on stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated.